# setState rebuilds the parent widget, causing a blink effect in FutureBuilders (because they rebuild?)

Tags: flutter, mobile

In my parent widget i have 2 FutureBuilders

**Image FutureBuilder**

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: scannedUserBloc.getImageUrl(widget.userId),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
                      child: Image.network(snapshot.data)
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text("Image is loading");
                }
              }
```

**List future builder**

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: scannedUserBloc.getMembershipPrograms(widget.userId),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        var programs = snapshot.data as List<MembershipPrograms>;
        if(programs.length > 0) {
          hasPrograms = true;
          return programsRowWidget(context, programs);
        } else {
          return noProgramsColumnWidget(context);
        }
      }else {
        //loading indicator
        return Container(

        );
      }
});
```

When i want to click on an item in the ListView, i want it to change its border, so it looks like it is selected. To do that, i need to call setState, but when i call it, it causes FutureBuilders to blink. That happens because (i'm assuming) the widgets rebuild, which causes the FutureBuilders to make the async call to the backend, making the items disappear temporary until the items are fetched again.

Is there any workaround or fix for this? Is the approach i'm taking bad in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate the `ListView` widget to different `Stateful` class. Then call `setState` from there. Then the `FutureBuilder` will not execute multiple times.

Comment: Worked, thank you! Do you have an idea how i can monitor from the parent widget which item is selected, and how to allow only one item to be selected at a time?

Comment: Great! You can give e required function field in the child class which parameter will be the selected item index. Then you can monitor it from the parent class.